# Finding distance traveled by a particle with given position

Tags: calculus

I came across this problem on my practice quiz for calculus that I ended up guessing on because I didn't know how to start it. I'm trying to learn it now for my upcoming exam, so any guidance would be helpful. Can anyone show me how to work through it?

> Find the distance traveled by a particle with position (x, y) as t varies in the given time 
>   interval. Compare with the length of the curve.
>   $$x = sin^2(\theta), y=cos^2(\theta), 0\le\theta\le4\pi$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hints**

Show that $x+y=1$. Which values can take $x$ and $y$? Where does the particle start? How far does it go? How many times?

Comment: Does the particle start at 0 and make two revolutions to get to 4pi?